# Convert Dictionary<string, List<object>> to List<Dictionary<string, object> in LINQ

Tags: linq, list, dictionary

How to convert `Dictionary<string, List<object>>` to `List<Dictionary<string, object>` in LINQ? I am doing it using for loop, any way to do it in a compact way?

```
Dictionary<string, List<object>> mydata = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>();
List<object> ldate=new List<object>(){"1/1/2000","1,1/2001"};
List<object> lage=new List<object>(){"4","5"};

mydata["date"] = ldate;
mydata["age"] = lage;

List<Dictionary<string, object>> mytarget = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
Dictionary<string,object> t1=new Dictionary<string,object>();
Dictionary<string,object> t2=new Dictionary<string,object>();

t1["date"]="1/1/2000";
t1["age"]="4";

t2["date"]="1/1/2001";
t2["age"]="5";

mytarget.Add(t1);
mytarget.Add(t2);
```

many thanks,
canric

Comment: Your data really isn't very clear, to be honest. It would help if you could show some actual data types and sample data... ideally in a short but complete program constructing the dictionary and with the expected list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Dictionary<string,List<object>> orig = ...
var res = Enumerable.Range(0, orig.Values.First().Count)
    .Select(
        i => orig.Aggregate(
            new Dictionary<string,object>()
        ,   (d, p) => { d[p.Key] = p.Value[i]; return d; }
        )
    ).ToList();
```

See a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/ymI4bW).

Comment: works! thank you, man. I copy/paste your code to replace my ugly for loop.

Comment: @canric You are welcome! Note that my implementation is not too different from your `for` loop, perhaps a bit more compact, but also harder to understand without sufficient Linq experience. Anyway, if the solution works for you, consider accepting the answer by clicking a check mark next to it. This would let others know that you are no longer actively looking for an improved solution, and earn you a badge on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I am working on a program which is written in pure linq. so I am kind of have to keep the same style. thanks again,

Answer (score 0):

I'll just give you simpler alternative without the tricky usage of aggregate:

```
var target = Enumerable.Range(0, source.Values.First().Count)
                   .Select(i => source.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value[i]))
                   .ToList();
```